# How do I separate a user input integer into spaced out digits in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
user1 = int(input(" Enter a 5 digit number.\n"))
```

How do i get the output printed in individual digits separated with blank spaces?

Comment: you should post your code so that we can tell what's wrong

Comment: Look for .split() method online. that is all the generic help I can give you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that print separates its arguments with a space, and use a starred expression to pass all digits of the number to print:

```
user1 = input("Enter a 5 digit number.\n")   #   no int(...) here

print(*user1)   #   if you use int(...) with the input, you should use *str(user1) here
```

Input:

```
16532
```

Output:

```
1 6 5 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
' '.join(list(str(user1))
```